# How to reset all DNS records on Samba?

Tags: domain-name-system, samba4

I've restored Samba data but the DNS records it holds is of `192.168.2.0/24` as opposed `192.168.0.0/24` network the system it was restored to operates on. As such, the AD can't even resolve itself properly. How may I reset all the records?

Tentatively, I've tried to add the server's IP using `samba-tool dns add`, but it asks for `DOMAIN\root` password instead of `DOMAIN\administrator` or `administrator@DOMAIN.SECRET.COM` as in the [Samba Wiki example](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/DNS_administration#Administering_DNS_on_Linux.2FUnix):

```
$ sudo samba-tool dns add localhost domain.international.com domain A 192.168.0.10
Password for [DOMAIN\root]:
```

I'm at my wit's end here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already in place the DNS configuration so I guess in this case you won't need to use `add` option but `update` because you are updating the DNS, right? Add `-U Administrator` to specify which user you want to make these changes as.

First, lookup all records, then use `update` to change them according to the new network:

```
samba-tool dns query localhost domain.international @ ALL -U administrator
samba-tool dns update localhost domain.international.com domain A oldIP newIP -U administrator
```

Comment: You're correct, but it's asking for the non-existent `DOMAIN/root` password to do so.

Comment: Okay, it seems `sudo` was the problem. `sudo samba-tool` made it ask for `DOMAIN\root`. Fortunately, I named the default Ubuntu account `Administrator`, so it asked for `DOMAIN\administrator` without `sudo`. Do you know of any command to list all records? I'll remove/update all problematic ones.